# Backbone extend broken

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

This has never previously happened and its leaving me a little miffed... But if I create a view and try to extend it `extend` isn't a function on a on appears like a valid instance of the class.

```
var gv = Backbone.View.extend({
    //Stuff here
});

console.log(gv);
//child {cid: "view2", $el: jQuery.fn.init[1], el: div.shell, constructor: function, events: Object…}

gv.extend({
    //Stuff here
});
//Uncaught TypeError: gv.extend is not a function
```

I have added a working example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var RN = {};

  RN.gvCreator = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.shell',
    render: function() {
      console.info('building stuff');
    }
  });
  //set up the global view for all menu items etc
  RN.gv = new RN.gvCreator();
  RN.gv.render();
  console.info(RN.gv);
  var indexView = RN.gv.extend({
    el: '.content',
    render: function() {
      console.info('working');
    }
  });

  Backbone.history.start();
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.2/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js"></script>
<div class="shell"></div>
```

Comment: Is gv within scope of where you're calling gv.extend({}); ?

Comment: Can you post your exact use?

Comment: @startswithaj I had wanted to post the code, but its rather complex with browserify. `But `gv.extend` is called in the same file as the `console.log`

Comment: As you correctly point out, gv seems to be an instance of a view rather than a constructor/function.

Comment: @startswithaj yes, but this isn't expected behaviour... It should have the function and be extenable.

Comment: Can you show us a little bit more of your particular usage? Are you using coffeescript?

Comment: I've added a working example of the error....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you reassign to `RN.gv`. At first it is a constructor, but then you clobber it with an instance.

Generally speaking, view instances cannot be extended after creation (at least not with that method).

You can solve your problem by having two separate variables for your constructor and instance. Just note that (re-)extending the constructor after instances have already been created will only affect future view instances- they will not retroactively affect previously created view instances.

---

**Edit**: In response to the comment below, this is how the new view extend should be done:

```
  var indexView = RN.gvCreator.extend({
    el: '.content',
    render: function() {
      console.info('working');
    }
  });
```

This will not affect the properties of `RN.gv`, since that was already created with the `RN.gvCreator` constructor. (Note that `RN.gvCreator` is not modified by the `extend` statement above-- instead, a new view constructor is created which uses `RN.gvCreator` as its base.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I have updated the code snippet to reflect what you suggested, I thought that this could be an issue. I am still getting the error :/ Have I done what you suggested correctly?

Comment: Not quite-- the new view constructor needs to be extended from `gvCreator` (the other view constructor), not the view instance. Backbone view instances don't have an extend method. (See updated answer)

Comment: Good lord baby Jesus!! You've done it. I admit though, whilst clearly I didn't know this before, I wonder how it worked previously... Differently no doubt lol

Answer (score 0):

Try extending the prototype object of your view using underscore:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
  foo: 1
});

console.log(View);

_.extend(View.prototype, {
  bar: 2
});

var aView = new View();

console.log(aView.foo);
console.log(aView.bar);
```

Comment: lol underscore? I am not having problems with JS templates... ? Unless I have misunderstod

Comment: Underscore does far more than create JS templates :-) Take a look at underscorejs.org for more information.

Comment: Take a look at the updated question :) This has a working example with my error.